# SharePoint 2010 not able to Edit excel document in IE11

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are using `editDocumentWithProgID2()` JavaScript function to edit the excel document from my SharePoint site,  However we are not able to edit the document using IE11, (able to edit Below IE10) and Chrome browser. Can you please guide me the solution to edit the document using IE11.

We have tried using “return DispEx” function also, but  it always saying Document is read only you cannot edit the document.

```
editDocumentWithProgID2(docURL, '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', '', '0');
```

Comment: is that working?

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft [KB2661910](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2661910) seems to match your situation 100%. It also come with a [Fix It](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9800241) in the article.

There are few workarounds mentioned in [this article](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/236628)